# Explode multiple array columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data farme in`pyspark`. I am trying to explode some array columns to create rows.

## create data frame

`df = spark.createDataFrame([('12345','0036',25),('12356','0036',24),('12347','0036',20)],("ext_contract", "legal_entity", "amount"))`

```
>>> df.show()
+------------+------------+------+
|ext_contract|legal_entity|amount|
+------------+------------+------+
|       12345|        0036|    25|
|       12356|        0036|    24|
|       12347|        0036|    20|
+------------+------------+------+
```

First array columm

`df.withColumn("array_source",array(f.lit('T2'),f.lit('T'), f.lit('S'))).withColumn("AFI_SOURCE",explode("array_source")).show()`

```
+------------+------------+------+------------+----------+
|ext_contract|legal_entity|amount|array_source|AFI_SOURCE|
+------------+------------+------+------------+----------+
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         T|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         S|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         T|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         S|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         T|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         S|
+------------+------------+------+------------+----------+
```

Second array column

`df.withColumn("INTRTP_ARRAY",array(f.lit('NWP'),f.lit(None), f.lit(None))).withColumn("INTRTP",explode("INTRTP_ARRAY")).show()`

```
+------------+------------+------+------------+------+
|ext_contract|legal_entity|amount|INTRTP_ARRAY|INTRTP|
+------------+------------+------+------------+------+
|       12345|        0036|    25|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12345|        0036|    25|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12356|        0036|    24|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12347|        0036|    20|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|     [NWP,,]|  null|
+------------+------------+------+------------+------+
```

As you see in both cases it is creating only `9` rows. But when I want try to cobine both the two array and `explode` it is creating many rows.

`df.withColumn("array_source",array(f.lit('T2'),f.lit('T'), f.lit('S'))).withColumn("AFI_SOURCE",explode("array_source")).withColumn("INTRTP_ARRAY",array(f.lit('NWP'),f.lit(None), f.lit(None))).withColumn("INTRTP",explode("INTRTP_ARRAY")).show()`

```
+------------+------------+------+------------+----------+------------+------+
|ext_contract|legal_entity|amount|array_source|AFI_SOURCE|INTRTP_ARRAY|INTRTP|
+------------+------------+------+------------+----------+------------+------+
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|        T2|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         T|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|   NWP|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|         S|     [NWP,,]|  null|
+------------+------------+------+------------+----------+------------+------+
```

expected result is below

```
+------------+------------+------+------------+------------+----------+------+
|ext_contract|legal_entity|amount|array_source|INTRTP_ARRAY|AFI_SOURCE|INTRTP|
+------------+------------+------+------------+------------+----------+------+
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|        T2|   NWP|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|         T|  null|
|       12345|        0036|    25|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|         S|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|        T2|   NWP|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|         T|  null|
|       12356|        0036|    24|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|         S|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|        T2|   NWP|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|         T|  null|
|       12347|        0036|    20|  [T2, T, S]|     [NWP,,]|         S|  null|
+------------+------------+------+------------+------------+----------+------+
```

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip + https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline